# Python: rodar um servidor aiohttp em um loop de eventos pré-existente

Tags: python, assincronismo

Tenho no meu software um loop de eventos do `asyncio` que está rodando diversas tarefas e agora quero adicionar um servidor HTTP para ouvir requisições vindas da rede local. Mas tem um problema: aparentemente, o "`App`", que é o servidor `aiohttp`, cria um loop de eventos próprio e não consigo encontrar um jeito de acoplá-lo ao meu loop. Veja o código abaixo:

```
import asyncio
from aiohttp import web

loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
loop.call_soon(lambda: print('O loop está rodando!'))

app = web.Application()
routes = web.RouteTableDef()


@routes.get('/')
async def index(request):
    print('Requisição recebida!')
    return web.Response(text='Resposta do server aiohttp')


app.add_routes(routes)
web.run_app(app)
loop.run_forever()
```

Estou criando um loop que deve fazer um `print` logo que ele começar a rodar. Logo em seguida, crio um servidor simples e começo a rodá-lo (penúltima linha, `web.run_app(app)`). Só que essa chamada bloqueia, então a linha `loop.run_forever()` nunca chega a ser executada. Não encontrei na API nenhuma função relacionada a executar em um loop externo.

Bem, eu poderia naturalmente usar threads para fazer isso, mas daí eu perderia todo o ponto de se usar assincronismo. Existe alguma maneira de executar um servidor aiohttp num loop de eventos externo?

Nota: para mim, é importante que isso seja feito assim porque este programa está destinado a rodar em um hardware limitado; todos os outros núcleos estarão destinados a cuidar de outras tarefas e a memória é escassa também. Logo, preciso que as atividades não tão cruciais (como esta) sejam abarcadas pelo loop. Como o colega @Augusto pontuou, em condições normais provavelmente seria mais inteligente transferir o servidor para um processo separado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim, é possível. Isso é o que a documentação do aiohttp chama de "*[low-level server](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/web_lowlevel.html#run-a-basic-low-level-server)*". No exemplo dado lá, o servidor é executado de dentro de uma sub-rotina que está destinada a acabar quando uma condição é preenchida (naquele caso, o servidor roda durante algum tempo e depois é encerrado). Isso é útil se você quer manter o servidor ativo durante uma *etapa* do seu código, onde caberia usar `asyncio.run`. Se você pretende manter o servidor rodando por tempo indeterminado enquanto faz outras coisas com o loop de eventos, veja o exemplo a seguir:

```
import asyncio
from aiohttp import web

loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()


async def setup_server():
    server = web.Server(handler=handle_server_request)
    runner = web.ServerRunner(server)
    await runner.setup()
    site = web.TCPSite(runner)
    await site.start()
    print('Servidor rodando em:', site.name)


async def handle_server_request(request):
    print('Requisição recebida, rota:', request.path)
    return web.Response(text='Resposta do server aiohttp')


loop.create_task(setup_server())
loop.call_soon(lambda: print('O loop está rodando!'))
loop.run_forever()
```

Chamo a atenção de que `server`, `runner` e `site` devem ser construídos dentro de uma corotina (uma função assíncrona). Se você quiser interromper o servidor em algum momento, você irá querer guardar a instância de `site`, pois ela possui um método `site.stop()`. É estranho que a biblioteca não ofereça a opção de vincular o servidor a um roteador, como foi feito no exemplo da pergunta. Isso te obriga a invocar as rotas apropriadas manualmente dentro da corotina `handle_server_request`.

Obviamente, é substancial que seja o seu loop externo que execute `setup_server`. Isso é feito na antepenúltima linha do exemplo: `loop.create_task(setup_server())`.
Se você usar `asyncio.run`, o servidor irá ser desligado tão logo quanto criado.

Comment: Por favor, se alguém tiver uma crítica quanto à pergunta ou à resposta, comente ou edite antes de dar voto negativo.

Comment: Concordo com você, tem acontecido bastante.

Comment: Não fui eu quem deu o negativo, mas posso entender o motivo pois é possivelmente um [Problema XY](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/499/137387) embarcar um Servidor Web no mesmo processo de sua aplicação. Não parece ser o melhor dos cenários importar o bloat e os gargalos do Servidor HTTP para aplicação principal. Talvez fosse melhor o web server ter o seu próprio processo o desacoplando da aplicação principal e assim utilizar pipes ou HTTP ou uma Fila de Mensagens para fazer a comunicação entre a aplicação principal e o servidor web.

Comment: Agora que vi, até o momento não há negativos nem na pergunta e nem na resposta.

Comment: Verifiquei sinalizações da comunidade aqui, e não notei nenhum negativo, mas quero aproveitar o momento para uma ressalva: é importante notar que a comunidade não deve esperar pra dar negativo nem positivo quando merecido (desde que feita uma análise justa, senão melhor a pessoa se abster de votar). Se qualquer post tiver problema, o negativo tem que ser dado até que a pessoa resolva, senão o sistema fica ineficaz; lembrem-se, votos não são avaliação de mérito pessoal, e sim um reflexo para classificar o **estado atual** de cada postagem (tanto que após uma edição, o voto pode ser trocado).

Comment: @AugustoVasques entendo tua crítica. Não sei se o meu caso específico se enquadre como um problema XY porque no projeto no qual estou trabalhando este software precisa rodar em um hardware muito limitado. Não há outros cores sobrando, pois eles estão incumbidos de tarefas mais pesadas ainda. Nesse cenário, rodar o servidor dentro de um loop compartilhado me aparenta ser uma boa decisão. Contudo, essa talvez seja uma realidade tão específica que não valesse a pena postar uma resposta aqui na SO. Seria o caso de excluir?

Comment: Excluir acho que não. Talvez editar a pergunta e apensar ao final da pergunta uma observação apresentando o caso, ou limitações, em que se faz necessário embarcar um servidor na aplicação.